# How to type cast elements of a huge array initialized with numbers

Tags: c, arrays, casting, type-conversion

I have a third party C code which has large arrays of type float initialized with floating point numbers. Example:

```
float myArray[] = {1.2, 2.5, ....}; /*has thousands of elements*/
```

When I compile, I get the warning "truncation from double to float". I would like to get rid of this warning. If the array size was small (e.g. two), I could use standard type casting and manually update the code as follows:

```
float myArray[] = {1.2f, 2.5f};
```

or

```
float myArray[] = {(float) 1.2, (float) (2.5)};
```

However, due to the large number of elements, updating manually is not practical. Do I have to write a script that edits the source code and puts "f" after the numbers or is there an easier way for type casting the whole array with just one casting? Example:

```
float myArray[] = (float){1.2, 2.5, ...} /*does not work, issues syntax error*/
```

Comment: Hey, check if the error is in this line. Cos, I tried a similar assignment, but I dont get any such warnings.

Comment: I think it's easier to get an editor supporting regex (there are many) and replace `(\.\d+)` with `$1f` in that range.

Comment: @Balanivash: I tried again and still get the warning. You might want to look at your compiler's warning settings.

Comment: I got a message saying `0 Errors, 0 warnings`

Comment: Replacing `,` with `f,` would fix your example. Most editors will do that easily.

Comment: @Balanivash It seems likely that you either have a compiler where floats and doubles are of equal size, or simply a crappier compiler than the OP.

Comment: what is the compiler you are using?

Comment: Mine is the compiler of Visual Studio 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a text editor with search and replace, such as MS notepad, then have it replace every occurrence of the string "," with "f,".